# Does the idea of the Big Bounce include the reversal of time?

Tags: spacetime

If spacetime is a single enitity, and the Big Bounce is the idea that space itself will collapse back in on itself, does that mean that time will collapse back in on itself? And... what does that look like?

Comment: *the Big Bounce is the idea that space itself will collapse back in on itself* As far as I know, this is not what the Big Bounce is. It’s the idea that if the universe collapses back to a near-singularity, it will expand again, perhaps just before reaching a singular state. If the universe were to stop expanding and start collapsing (which now seems unlikely) that wouldn’t be anything like a bounce. It would be like the top of a trajectory when you throw a ball into the air. The bounce comes when the ball gets back to the ground, not at the top.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bounce